# TADOConnection with SQL Server Thread with Delphi

Tags: sql, multithreading, delphi, adoconnection

I am working on a project and I need to think about emergency situations.

The main issue is, how to check if the database is connected (circle object = red or green)?

`BeforeConnect`, `AfterDisconnect`, they have no good answer.

Inside type:

Create Connection:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  s : String;
begin
  ADOConnectionSQL := TADOConnection.Create(nil);
  ADOConnectionSQL.LoginPrompt := false;
  with ADOSQL do
  begin
    s := 'Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;'+
    'Persist Security Info=False;'+
    'User ID='+Edit1.Text+';'+
    'Initial Catalog='+Edit2.Text+';'+
    'Data Source='+Edit3.Text+';'+
    'Initial File Name="";'+
    'Server SPN="";'+
    'password="'+Edit4.Text+'"';
    ADOConnectionSQL.ConnectionString := s;
  end;
  ADOConnectionSQL.BeforeConnect := SQLConnected;
  ADOConnectionSQL.AfterDisconnect := SQLDisconnected;
end;
```

Try to connect:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Thread : TThread;
begin
  Thread := TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    begin
      TThread.Synchronize(TThread.CurrentThread,
      procedure
        begin
        try
          ADOConnectionSQL.Connected := True;
          ADOConnectionSQL.Open;
        except
          on E: Exception do
          begin
            ShowMessage('Exception message = '+E.Message);
          end;
        end;
        ADOQuerySQL := TADOQuery.Create(nil);
      end);
    end);
  Thread.OnTerminate := FinishConnected;
  Thread.Start;
end;
```

Green or Red:

```
procedure TForm1.SQLConnected(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Circle1.Fill.Color := $FF00FF00;
end;

procedure TForm1.SQLDisconnected(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Circle1.Fill.Color := $FFFF0000;
end;
```

FinishConnected:

```
procedure TForm1.FinishConnected(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if TThread(Sender).FatalException <> nil then
  begin
    // something went wrong
    ShowMessage ('Failure to connection');
    //Exit;
  end;
end;
```

When the SQL Server is online, I would like to see a green circle. When the connection with server goes downs, the circle should be red.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating and opening the ADO connection in the context of the main UI thread, not in the context of the worker thread.  So your worker thread is basically useless.  You could have just used `TThread.ForceQueue()` instead to get the same effect.

ADO uses COM technology internally, so you can't really use it across thread boundaries anyway.  If you want to use ADO in a thread, give the thread its own ADO Connection and Query objects. Do all your SQL work in the context of the thread, and synchronize status updates with the main UI thread as needed.

Also, you need to initialize the COM library in the worker thread before it can work with ADO.

Try something more like this instead:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Thread : TThread;
  ConnStr: string;
begin
  ConnStr := 'Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;'+
    'Persist Security Info=False;'+
    'User ID='+Edit1.Text+';'+
    'Initial Catalog='+Edit2.Text+';'+
    'Data Source='+Edit3.Text+';'+
    'Initial File Name="";'+
    'Server SPN="";'+
    'password="'+Edit4.Text+'"';

  Thread := TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    var
      ADOConnectionSQL: TADOConnection;
      ADOQuerySQL: TADOQuery;
    begin
      CoInitialize(nil);
      try
        ADOConnectionSQL := TADOConnection.Create(nil);
        try
          ADOConnectionSQL.LoginPrompt := False;
          ADOConnectionSQL.ConnectionString := ConnStr;

          ADOConnectionSQL.Open;

          TThread.Queue(nil,
            procedure
            begin
              Circle1.Fill.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Green;
            end
          );

          ADOQuerySQL := TADOQuery.Create(nil);
          try
            ADOQuerySQL.Connection := ADOConnectionSQL;
            // use ADOQuerySQL as needed...
          finally
            ADOQuerySQL.Free;
          end;
        finally
          ADOConnectionSQL.Free;
        end;
      finally
        CoUninitialize;
      end;
    end);
  Thread.OnTerminate := SQLFinished;
  Thread.Start;
end;

procedure TForm1.SQLFinished(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Circle1.Fill.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Red;
  if TThread(Sender).FatalException <> nil then
  begin
    // something went wrong
    ShowMessage('Failure! ' + Exception(TThread(Sender).FatalException).Message);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, I tried, and works. I believe that I was not 100% clear. When I try to connect with the database and the IP is wrong, the software will be locked until complete the timeout (You fixed this), but I would like to make the circle green all the time that the connection is available and red when it goes down. Maybe a timer to fix this. Do you have any idea?

Comment: No timer is needed. The code I provided will handle what you want just fine. Simply make the circle be red initially, since the thread is not running yet. Then, the thread will set the circle to green only if `Open()` is successful, and then set it back to red when the thread terminates for any reason.  I would also suggest adding a 3rd color, say yellow, for when the thread is being created but has not called `Open()` yet, so the user can see that the app is busy trying to connect.